# I get the following error when trying to create a component: ng new routing-demo

Tags: angular

error: The new command requires to be run outside of a project, but a project definition was found at "C:\Windows\System32\routing-demo\angular.json".

Comment: Hello, welcome. It's very difficult to help you if we don't have more data. Please update your question. Where are you trying to run the comand? Are you in the terminal? Could you share a screenshot from your terminal?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The correct command to generate an angular component is :
`ng generate component <component-name>`

**Example:**

`ng generate component routing-demo`

**To create a new angular app:**

`ng new <app-name>`

You are trying to create a new angular app with `ng new` command inside an existing project. Therefore you get the following error:

> error: The new command requires to be run outside of a project, but a
> project definition was found at
> "C:\Windows\System32\routing-demo\angular.json".